# Apache rewrite: add CGI handler before every request path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi

I have a directory hosting a Sinatra web application. Due to some hosting restrictions, I have to launch this app via a CGI script; however, I've written it to parse out the URL path portion, rather than just the query string. As such, most of my requests are written as:

`GET /point/get HTTP/1.0`

However, due to the CGI script, the actual URL called is (for example) http://server.com/script.cgi/point/get.

Is there a way, using mod_rewrite, to insert that `script.cgi/` into every request that comes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/script\.cgi/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/script\.cgi/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.cgi/$1 [L,R]
```

This will do **external redirect**.

For an **internal redirect** replace last line with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is almost working, but isn't stopping after a single addition - instead, it's looping, adding `/server.cgi/server.cgi/...` until the browser stops following redirects.

Comment: I updated my answer. For external redirect it was working fine but for an internal one it was looping so I have now provided both options.